# search about specific value from mysql by android

Tags: android

The database is connected and every thing is good but it only present first value of results

the code of PHP:

$res['medicine_name'],
            "ID_P"=>$res['ID_Pharmacy'],
            "id_M"=>$res['id_M']
            )
        );

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

        mysqli_close($con);

    }
    ?>

And this is code in android:

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.gettingspecificdata;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextId;
    private Button buttonGet;
    private TextView textViewResult;

    private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNameM);
        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void SearchMedicine() {
        String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
        if (id.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an medicine name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL +editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){
        String nameOfMedicine="";
        String IDPharmacy="";
        String IDMedicine = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject searchData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            nameOfMedicine = searchData.getString(Config.KEY_MEDICINE_NAME);
            IDPharmacy = searchData.getString(Config.KEY_ID_PHARMACY);
            IDMedicine = searchData.getString(Config.KEY_ID_MEDICINE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Name of medicine:\t"+nameOfMedicine+"\nID Pharmacy:\t" +IDPharmacy+ "\nID Medicine:\t"+ IDMedicine);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        SearchMedicine();
    }
}
```

The output:
[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s76Pb.png)

Comment: Your code is only parsing the first element of the JSON returned.  You're going to have to parse all of them, and you're going to have to implement a UI that can display more than 1 at a time-  likely a ListView, but other solutions also work.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the  showJSON method, you are not iterating the JSON Array to get each JSON object and append it to the TextView. Just takes the first one.

Correct showJSON ()

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    String nameOfMedicine="";
    String IDPharmacy="";
    String IDMedicine = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        textViewResult.setText("");
        for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++){
                JSONObject searchData = result.getJSONObject(i);
                nameOfMedicine = searchData.getString(Config.KEY_MEDICINE_NAME);
                IDPharmacy = searchData.getString(Config.KEY_ID_PHARMACY);
                IDMedicine = searchData.getString(Config.KEY_ID_MEDICINE);
        String temp = textViewResult.getText()+" \n";
        textViewResult.setText(temp+"Name of medicine:\t"+nameOfMedicine+"\nID Pharmacy:\t" +IDPharmacy+ "\nID Medicine:\t"+ IDMedicine);
    }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: repeat the same value every click on button search donot take another value

Comment: Actually i can't understand what you are telling. any way add `textViewResult.setText("")` befor the loop to stop appending same value for textview. answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

this is php:

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

        $medicine_name  = $_GET['medicine_name'];

        //$id  = $_GET['id'];

        require_once('dbConnectp.php');

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM medicine WHERE medicine_name='".$medicine_name."' AND stuteus='avilable'";

         //SELECT * FROM `medicine` WHERE `medicine_name` LIKE 'M1'
        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM Get WHERE id='".$id."'"; WHERE medicine_name=$Name_medicine

        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

        $result = array();

        array_push($result,array(
            "medicine_name"=>$res['medicine_name'],
            "ID_P"=>$res['ID_Pharmacy'],
            "id_M"=>$res['id_M']
            )
        );

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

        mysqli_close($con);

    }
    ?>
```